# Calculating longitude distortion on approach to poles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, latitude-longitude

I'm working on a game in which players are trying to target points on a sphere.

As targets approach the poles, the game should become more forgiving in longitude because the ratio of longitude distance to latitude distance grows. At the poles, the game should be infinitely forgiving in longitude.

What formula am I looking for that tells me how much longitudinal distance equals 1 unit of latitudinal distance for a particular latitude? Assume that longitude and latitude are expressed as floats ranging from 0-1, and at the equator (0.5) longitude equals latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula is rather simple (for usual spherical coordinates with `-Pi/2..Pi/2` latitude range):

```
Lon_Lat_Ratio = Cos(Latitude)
```

But your parametrization is different, so

```
Lon_Lat_Ratio = Sin(Latitude_01 * Pi)
```

Ratio is 1 on equator and 0 at poles

Comment: Why not just calculate the great circle distance between the player and the target?

Comment: @John Machin Emm.. I just missed part about player/target  and answered concrete question.